# Error - PHP - cURL - Unknown SSL protocol error in connection -

Tags: php, curl

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $xml_url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);

$xml = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_exec($ch) === false) 
{ echo curl_error($ch); }
else 
{ echo 'Operation completed without any errors'; }

curl_close($ch);
return $xml;
```

Above code is giving below error.

> Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api.site.com:443

As per suggested by many people that below code will resolve above issue but it is not helping. Still getting same error.

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
```

I tried below also as per suggestions but still getting same error.

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 'CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv3' );
```

Please suggest what else I should put in code to fix this error.

Thank you,

Comment: which curl version are you using?

Comment: @DarshanJain, libcurl/7.21.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8q zlib/1.2.3 - this is mentioned in php info.

Answer (score 1):

You just ignored the SSL certificate verification, may be it will help you to resolve the problem, use the code below when requesting with CURL.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Comment: Ty for your reply but still getting same error even after using above mentioned code.

Answer (score 1):

You could check which TLS version the website uses with curl verbose mode:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
```

Where the output will be like this:

```
...
SSL connection using TLS1.0 / RSA_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA1
...
```

Then set **CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST** like this:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, "TLSv1");
```

Where "TLSv1" is the TLS version the website uses.

Changing SSL version and VERIFY_PEER/HOST in curl options didn't solve my problem, but this approach did.

Comment: Using PHP curl, where does this output show up? I'm using CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true, and added CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true, and sending a head request with CURLOPT_NOBODY, true, but the call to curl_exec returns an empty string, and curl_getinfo()  does not produce it.

Comment: Oops, I see this is answered  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14436877/467590)

Answer (score 0):

You may try this code.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $xml_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

$xml = curl_exec($ch);

if($xml === false) { 
    echo curl_error($ch); 
}else{ 
    echo 'Operation completed without any errors'; 
}
curl_close($ch);
return $xml;
```

Also you may use this class for curl request,

https://gist.github.com/sourovroy/1fba93188470bbe3eefa15cd17533b23